# Perl telnet login

Tags: perl, telnet

*$remote->waitfor('/Logoff/');*

I get error sometimes saying that pattern match timed out when server is unavailable. I want to handle this error. Whenever this error occurs i want to make my script sleep for 1 minute and try to re-login.

I have tryied something like this:

```
  if($remote->waitfor('/Logoff/')) 
   {
     #proceed login perform intended operations.
   }
   else
   {
      sleep(60);#control is not coming here. returning pattern match timed-out error.
   }
```

Comment: Aaaaand, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way most of "**Net::Telnet**" methods are handling errors is defined by the "*errmode*" options.

This include of course the `waitfor` method and timeout errors.
The default "*errmode*" behaviour is "die", meaning that your `waitfor` call will return nothing and go no-where.

To have a value to check, you need to set the "*errmode*" to "**return**":

```
 if($remote->waitfor( -match => '/Logoff/', -errmode => 'return' )) 
   {
     #proceed login perform intended operations.
   }
   else
   {
      sleep(60); #returning pattern match timed-out error (or something else).
   }
```

NB: As you specify additional options to `waitfor`, you need to set the match pattern through the "*match*" option.

Comment: Excellent. Its working fine thanks for your quick answer. Great work keep it up. Thank you very much once again.